# Npm warn depracated fixes / parcel installation

Tags: javascript, node.js

So I was able to install nodejs and access npm from my command line and couldn't get it to work on my vscode and also couldn't get parcel to work on my command linr

I don't know if anyone can help me with this, I'm getting really frustrated I've watched every tutorials and read documentations but still can't get it to work

Comment: Please provide us with your attempts snippets, what have you done. some example or any error message what you are getting. It is currently unclear what are you asking for.

Comment: Okay the first problem, after installing node js. I was able to access the npm module from the command line but whenever I try to use vs-code terminal I always get command not found

Comment: try running npm on cmd, and power shell if it works on both of them. if you can't then try checking the %PATH% environment variable. if even that doesn't work. please report

Comment: That's exactly what I don't understand it works on power line and command prompt but whenever I try to use any vs code terminal its always command not found

Comment: Specify the versions you are using

Comment: delete the vs code current terminal and create a new terminal then retry